# Visualforce generated MS Word .doc does not show file Preview

Tags: visualforce, content, contenttype, ms-word

I'm generating an `MS Word` document `.doc` in Visualforce using markup as below:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" contentType="application/msword#myDocument.doc" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" cache="true" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
<body>

[... some normal content for the document ...]

</body>
</html>
```

The document generates fine. I can download it, and open it in MS Word. There are no issues there. But the `Preview` that Salesforce do for all Files and Content (when we open the generated File in Detail View), that shows `Preview unavailable` message always.

[image]

How can this be fixed? is there anything I can do in generating Word from Visualforce, that I can restore the preview of file. I can confirm that, if I upload a Word document (natively generated in MS Word), I can see the preview alright.

Comment: It looks like the page is labeling an HTML file as .DOC rather than generating a "real" binary or MS XML format .DOC file, and I am not surprised the previewer balks at the mismatch between the format and the content.

Comment: Actually, .DOCX is supposed to be XML formatted document, while .DOC can be html. The html implemented way is the only available way to generate WORD document from Salesforce in a `native` way. The HTML formatted .DOC document is opened perfectly fine by MS Word as well (same way we can generate XLS file as well)

Comment: Microsoft Word has many, many years of development invested in it to be able to do things like convert a HTML file into Word's binary format on the fly. I'm not surprised that whatever viewer Salesforce is using is not equally tolerant. Also the last lime I looked the XML files in a .docx are zipped together and that zipping can't be done on the server-side in Salesforce.